# Assist vs Support

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

**The intern supports the team**

vs

**The intern assists the team**

Support = he took an active role in the team's work like he was just another employee

vs

Assist = he was given a couple tasks by the employees to help them get their work done faster

Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

The two verbs overlap. In many contexts, either would be suitable. In others, one or the other may sound more natural.

For example, here **support** is more idiomatic.

> She supported her family financially after her father had died.

and here **assist**.

> He assisted his brothers to carry their father's coffin.

It's not really useful to try to decide exactly what the words **assist** and **support** signify in your two examples. People would interpret them in the light of their own experience.

Comment: If you were a hiring manager and an intern told you that he wants to assist/support the finance department, which one should they use ?

Comment: I would use neither. The intern might **assist (people) in** the finance department. Certainly **support** does not work in this context.

Comment: so you'd say assist the finance team. I thought support was better because I found this : 'assist is a helpful action or an act of giving while support is something which supports often used attributively, as a complement or supplement to.'

Comment: @marquis20019 Our choice of words depends mainly on our experience of their usage. That's what I based my answer on. But, if you are more comfortable with **support**, there's nothing to stop you using it.